# How to execute Hive Query in Spark with more speed

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

## EXECUTE HIVE QUERIES IN TEZ AND SPARK

1. I have hive query running in **tez** taking 10 min
2. executed same query in **spark** using hivecontext.sql taking 13-14min

#### Hardware Info

Spark-1.5.2

Cluster-Yarn (in client mode)

Nodes- 11, memory-192GB, Cores-24

#### To Achieve

Like to execute in spark less than 5 min without changing my query

#### My Findings

> executors driverMemory    ExecutorMemory  Cores   start   end difference
>
> 4,    6,  15, 6,  17:12:15,   17:26:03,   0:13:48
>
> 4,    6,  15, 10, 17:37:55,   17:49:24,   0:11:29
>
> 4,    6,  7,  10, 17:53:40,   18:07:12,   0:13:32
>
> 1,    6,  7,  4,  21:54:10,   22:08:16,   0:14:06
>
> 1,    6,  7,  6,  23:44:15,   23:57:25,   0:13:10
>
> 3,    N/a,    60, 5,  11:12:49,   11:28:58,   0:16:09
>
> ```
> However I use it it is **not reducing execution time**.
> Can please someone let me know how to tune it
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is because spark 1.5.2 did not use tungsten engine. 
Check out the discussion here [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/33484/spark-sql-query-execution-is-very-very-slow-when-c.html)

Comment: used without tungsten 4, 6, 15, 10, 17:37:55, 17:49:24, 0:11:29   and             with tungsten    4 6 15 10 11:22:38 11:36:34 0:13:56 @Sanket_patil